# How to use CocoaPods with multiple Framework subprojects

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, cocoapods

First of all, I've turned on use_framework! in Podfile.

Assume the main project is MAIN_APP, and two subprojects are FRAMEWORK_A and FRAMEWORK_B.

MAIN_APP requires FRAMEWORK_A and FRAMEWORK_B, and FRAMEWORK_B requires FRAMEWORK_A as well.

All projects/targets are using CocoaPods to manage third party libraries.

For now, my Podfile looks like:

```
target :MAIN_APP do
    project 'MAIN_APP'
    pod 'PodA'
end

target :FRAMEWORK_A do
    project 'FRAMEWORK_A'
    pod 'PodB'
end

target :FRAMEWORK_B do
    project 'FRAMEWORK_B'
    pod 'PodC'
end
```

I manually added FRAMEWORK_A to build settings of FRAMEWORK_B, and both FRAMEWORK_A and FRAMEWORK_B to build settings of MAIN_APP.

All code compiles well, but when running the MAIN_APP crashes because it cannot load Framework of PodB.

I know I can manually add PodB to MAIN_APP and FRAMEWORK_B as well, but is it possible to define this kind of target dependency in Podfile?

Btw, when `pod install`, I got the warning:

> [!] The Podfile contains framework targets, for which the Podfile does not contain host targets (targets which embed the framework).
>
> If this project is for doing framework development, you can ignore this message. Otherwise, add a target to the Podfile that embeds these frameworks to make this message go away (e.g. a test target).

As I know, I can use nested target for host targets like:

```
target :FRAMEWORK_A
    target :MAIN_APP
    end
end
```

So CocoaPods will setup MAIN_APP to use FRAMEWORK_A and inherit pod dependencies from FRAMEWORK_A. But seems I cannot do it with multiple dependencies like:

```
target :FRAMEWORK_A
    target :MAIN_APP
    end
end
target :FRAMEWORK_B
    target :MAIN_APP
    end
end
```

Because target :MAIN_APP cannot be declared twice.

Is there any better solutions instead of defining pod dependencies as a function in Podfile and include in all target?

Comment: any progress? did u solved this?

Comment: @zaxy78 I split it into separate sub-projects instead of targets, because I noticed if they're in one project, although they're added to different targets, you can import headers with `"Header.h"`, but I want to enforce using `<Header.h>` to import headers from Frameworks.

Comment: We have a similar structure and it has caused some weirdness as I've migrated to the latest version of XCode & CocoaPods. Currently trying to debug how to best manage this style of podfile.

Comment: One important thing to mention is that when I drag the Pods.framework to the main project, seems it's referenced with an absolute path, so I updated it to a relative path to `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`, then for different target, it compiles with correct build of Pods framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can also get around this by just making `FrameworkA` and `FrameworkB` into local (static library) pods and it will de-duplicate everything for you and integrate it into the host app properly.

Examples: https://github.com/rob-keepsafe/PodFrameworksIssue

- `master` branch shows duplicate classes and umbrella frameworks like you have
- `deduped` branch makes the internal dynamic frameworks into local pods (as static libs) to de-dupe and still link in the dependencies

Comment: Thank you for the only solution to my problem on two projects, may God bless you.

Comment: Glad it helped @Nikaaner!

Answer (score 7):

This is a great question and I've struggled with a similar situation. This is my PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

workspace 'mygreatapp.xcworkspace'

project 'app/MyGreatApp/MyGreatApp.xcodeproj'
project 'platform/MyGreatFramework/MyGreatFramework.xcodeproj'

abstract_target 'This can say whatever you want' do

    target 'MyGreatApp' do
        project 'app/MyGreatApp/MyGreatApp.xcodeproj'
        pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0'
        pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 1.5'
        pod 'PromiseKit/Join'
        pod 'KVOController', '~> 1.0'
        pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
        pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.3'
        pod 'SSZipArchive'
    end

    target 'MyGreatAppTests' do
        project 'app/MyGreatApp/MyGreatApp.xcodeproj'
        pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.1'
    end

    target 'MyGreatFramework' do
        project 'platform/MyGreatFramework/MyGreatFramework.xcodeproj'
        pod 'SSZipArchive'
    end

    target 'MyGreatFrameworkTests' do
        project 'platform/MyGreatFramework/MyGreatFramework.xcodeproj'
        pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.1'
    end

    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
end
```

As you can see I'm not using frameworks and I use an `abstract_target` to group it all together. I wish these kinds of dependencies were easier to do in CocoaPods. I know this doesn't really answer your question but it might be helpful nonetheless.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an actual answer, but rather just another sample Podfile?

Comment: My Podfile is the same as yours. The problem is that when target 'MyGreatFramework' do pod 'Crashlytics' .`objc[15419]: Class xxx is implemented in both app and framework, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined`,I get warning on my app startup.Do you have a solution on this?

Comment: It may not be obvious to everyone reading this (if a person has only every done simple pod installs), but the trick is to have your Podfile in the parent directory that comprises your project and subprojects. Once I realized this, the above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure your issue is the same as mine, but I'm going to leave my solution here just-in-case someone has a similar issue.

I have a project with multiple sub-projects I use to modularize my code (and potentially prepare to extract to my own private pods).
I had the issue of one importing an external pod to one of the sub-projects, and receiving a dyld error due to a "missing image".

I found this Medium article from which I concluded that I had to always include the pods in the main project for the sub-projects to be able to find them. Neither of my external pods are used in the main project.
( https://medium.com/@akfreas/how-to-use-cocoapods-with-your-internal-ios-frameworks-192aa472f64b )
(I'm probably not writing the podfile as correctly or efficiently as I could, but this seems to fix my issue)

My podfile is therefore as follows:

```
abstract_target "RandomName" do

    target "MainProject" do
        inherit! :complete
        workspace './MainProject.xcodeproj'
        pod 'Moya', '~> 13.0'
        pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 17.0'
    end

    target "ModuleA" do
      project './ModuleA/ModuleA.xcodeproj'
      workspace './ModuleA/ModuleA.xcodeproj'
      pod 'Moya', '~> 13.0'
    end

    target "ModuleB" do
      project './ModuleB/ModuleB.xcodeproj'
      workspace './ModuleB/ModuleB.xcodeproj'
      pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 17.0'
    end
end
```

Comment: I always come  back to this article when setting up projects that (still) use cocoapods.