# Cocoapods how to share the same target to other multiple targets

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

I use react-native only in target3 that as a framework belong to target1, there is a target2 copy by target1 . then, how to share target3 to both target1 & target2. the blew Podfile is error with `The target 'target3' is declared twice for the project 'Target3/Target3.xcodeproj'.`

```
target 'target1' do
  use_frameworks!

  target 'target3' do
    use_frameworks!

    react_native_path = 'node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React', :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'BatchedBridge',
    ]
  end
end

target 'target2' do
  use_frameworks!

  target 'target3' do
    use_frameworks!

    react_native_path = 'node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React', :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'BatchedBridge',
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Awesome! I got the inspiration inadvertently when I search for  another Cocoapods question.**

```
// with your own workspace
workspace 'myApp.xcworkspace' 

// declare the project path you will add blew
project 'Project1.xcodeproj'
project 'Project2.xcodeproj'

// abstract_target with any target name as you like
abstract_target 'target' do 

  target 'Project1' do
    use_frameworks!
    project 'LessChat-iOS.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Alamofire'
 end

 target 'Project2' do
   use_frameworks!
   project 'Project2.xcodeproj'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  end
end
```

All above, hope it can help you = =

**more detail or similiar situation see**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43739900/5557953

thanks @Johannes Fahrenkrug